# Compare 2 instance objects and find uncommon elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 instance objects : @original_files and @version2_files

I want to retrieve the elements found in  @original_files but NOT FOUND in @version2_files.

The code below:

```
<% @original_files.each do |original_file| %>

  <% @version2_files.each do |ver2_file| %>
    <% if original_file.name ==  ver2_file.name%>
      <%= original_file.name %> is common to both sets
      <% break %>
      <% else %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me figure out how to find the elements found in  @original_files only.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are arrays?  You can subtract...

```
@original_files - @version2_files
```

Hashes can use [diff](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-diff).

```
 @original_files.diff(@version2_files)
```

Comment: FYI this method has been depricated

Answer (score 1):

I understand this to mean that @original_files and @version2_files are hashes, and you want to find elements in @original_files that are not in @version2_files

```
@original_files.keys - @version2_files.keys
```

Answer (score 1):

*disclaimer:* new to ruby and may be ignorant of how hashes/arrays work exactly.

@danh's answer is right if you want to compare on key/value pairs. But if you're comparing the 2 hashes based on their values only and the keys are not important, then `diff` may not be what you need. In which case, you would do something like:

```
original.values - version2.values => [ ... ]
```

which returns an array of elements found only in `original` but not `version2`.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928789/how-do-i-compare-two-hashes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766741/comparing-ruby-hashes) may help.