# Compare json response with array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash, rspec

When I get an array of objects in JSON response, they might be represent in a different order.

Sometimes I get this

```
JSON.parse(response.body) # => [{"a" => "b"}, {"c" => "d"}]
```

or this

```
JSON.parse(response.body) # => [{"c" => "d"}, {"a" => "b"}]
```

But for me both results are correct. What is the easiest way to test which objects I have in response regardless of their order?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing ruby hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766741/comparing-ruby-hashes)

Comment: Do you want to compare the two or do you just want to check for the existence of certain keys?

Comment: @padde, I want to compare two or more hashes in the array. But I don't want to compare their order in the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare two hashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928789/how-do-i-compare-two-hashes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it into a set-like structure using a hash.

```
first_response.inject({}){|s, h| s[h] = true; s}
```

will be the same as

```
second_response.inject({}){|s, h| s[h] = true; s}
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with its other useful features, the [json spec](https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec) gem has a `be_json_eql` matcher which works without respect to order.

Comment: I'm not sure `be_json_eql` is order independent. The code looks like  `@actual, @expected = scrub(actual_json, @path), scrub(@expected_json)` and then does a straight `@actual == @expected`. the `scrub` method is in charge of excluding keys you don't want to be part of the comparison (e.g. `updated_at`), and 'normalizing' the JSON, which just calls either `JSON.pretty_generate` or `to_json`.