# compare 2 hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing ruby hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766741/comparing-ruby-hashes)

How can I compare two hashes and show only if name was matching correctly.

```
element1 = {:name => "Original", :description => "The original one!"}
element2 = {:name => "Original", :description => ""}
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of the output that you should get given those two hashes?

Answer (score 2):

If a reverse of a diff is what you want then you could try this.

```
class Hash
  def in_both(other)
    self.keys.inject({}) do |memo, key|
      memo[key] = self[key] if self[key] == other[key]
      memo
    end
  end
end

> element1.in_both(element2)
=> {:name=>"Original"}
```

or the much shorter

```
element1.select{|k,v| element2[k]==v}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for

```
element1[:name] == element2[:name]
```

Or be more specific, please.